# Unable to retrieve user data with specific phone number using SEQUELIZE Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have created two associated tables (Account, AccountCLI) using SEQUELIZE in Nodejs. Account table has many association with AccountCLI table. Account table has column(userid, eppusername, username, vendorsparameter, projectid). AccountCLI table has column(phonenumber, userid(ForeignKey)). When a user enter a phonenumber, it will return the corresponding userdata. In my code, it returns all the user data rather than specific user with the phone number. You can find the code below. Please give some suggestion?

The tables entries are shown as:

```
  'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Account = sequelize.define('Account', {
    epprojectname: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    projectid: DataTypes.STRING,
    vendorparameters: DataTypes.STRING,
    credentials: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Account.associate = function(models) {
    Account.hasMany(models.AccountCLI, {
      as: 'accountcli',
      foreignKey: 'userid'
    });
  };
  return Account;
};

'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const AccountCLI = sequelize.define('AccountCLI', {
    phonenumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    userid: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  AccountCLI.associate = function(models) {
    AccountCLI.belongsTo(models.Account, {
      as: "account",
      foreignKey: 'userid'   
     });
  };
  return AccountCLI;
};
```

The code (that suppose to retrieve specific user data) retrieving all the user data when entered a phone number value are shown as (This is the code after the suggestions):

```
        // find account with specific number 
exports.findSpecificUser = async (req, res) => {
var whereStatement = {};
if(req.body.phonenumber)
whereStatement['$accountcli.phonenumber$'] = {$like: '%' + req.body.phonenumber + '%'};
  Account.findAll({  include: { model: AccountCLI, as: "accountcli", where: whereStatement } })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving account with the specific phonenumber.",
      });
    });
};
```

This is the JSON file which I retrieved using POSTMAN. Here I put (phonenumber, 3334) which suppose to retrieve ("epprojectname": "DFSumitayayabot") userdata, but it retrieves both of the user info.

```
[
    {
        "id": 68,
        "epprojectname": "DFSumitayayabot",
        "username": "Sumit",
        "projectid": "ayayabot",
        "vendorparameters": "newparameters",
        "credentials": "1589956379476-tslint.json",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T15:23:00.440Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T06:36:05.903Z",
        "accountcli": [
            {
                "id": 227,
                "phonenumber": "33344",
                "userid": 68,
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T06:36:05.997Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T06:36:05.997Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 228,
                "phonenumber": " 447467",
                "userid": 68,
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T06:36:05.997Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T06:36:05.997Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 67,
        "epprojectname": "DFZeyadavayachatbot",
        "username": "Zeyad",
        "projectid": "avayachatbot",
        "vendorparameters": "{\"synth_speech_cfg\": { \"voice\": { \"name\": \"en-AU-Wavenet-C\"}}}",
        "credentials": "1589958578216-AppointmentType.json",
        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T15:17:43.399Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T07:09:38.228Z",
        "accountcli": [
            {
                "id": 249,
                "phonenumber": "44433",
                "userid": 67,
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T07:09:38.332Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T07:09:38.332Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 250,
                "phonenumber": " 5566",
                "userid": 67,
                "createdAt": "2020-05-20T07:09:38.332Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T07:09:38.332Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You should put `where: whereStatement` inside `include`.

Comment: @Emma I have put the whereStatement inside include, but still it returns all the userdata

Comment: You should keep the original `whereStatement['phonenumber'] = {$like: '%' + req.body.phonenumber + '%'};` and put into `include`. 
The key in the `where` should be relative to the model in the same level.  
Or move it back at top level and use @Anatoly's `whereStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

The **phonenumber** field is in AccountCLI model but you added a condition with the field in the Account query. 
Try something like this:

```
if(req.body.phonenumber)
  whereStatement['$accountcli.phonenumber$'] = {$like: '%' + req.body.phonenumber + '%'};
```

Comment: Still it return the all the user data rather than specific one.

Comment: select epprojectname from account, accountcli where account.ccaiuser_id = accountcli.ccaiuser_id and phonenumber ='3334';

Comment: Hmm. This `select` does not look like it from sequelize and it does not match the sequelize query that you show in the post. Please add the SQL query that is a result of the sequelize query in the post.

Comment: I want to implement above SQL query to Node using SEQUILIZE. As I am new to Node, may be my SEQUELIZE query is not correct. I want to retrieve epprojectname from database with phone number as input from my angular side. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to indicate `required: true` after `{ model: AccountCLI, `

Comment: It didn't work as well. There is some problem in my logic. With or without key, it is sending all the user data.

Comment: If you absolutely sure that a condition in `if(req.body.phonenumber)` is true then show result SQL

Comment: Yopu can do this by setting by sequelize to log into console